# IF AND OR together in one formula

Tags: visualforce, if, contains

I want to write a formula for the following:

Return Value A IF:

- Intake__c.Personal_Care__c contains 'toileting/bathing'
- OR Intake__c.Safety__c contains 'entering or exiting' AND Intake__c.Personal_Care__c contains
  'toileting/bathing'
- OR Intake__c.Safety__c contains 'confusion or dimentia' AND Intake__c.Personal_Care__c contains 'toileting/bathing'

How can I make this return true without getting an error?

```
{!IF
        (OR (CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing'), 
           (AND (CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety__c, 'entering or exiting the home/answering the door'), 
               (OR (CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing/self care in bathroom')))
           (AND (CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety__c, 'confusion or dimentia'), 
               (OR (!CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing/self care in bathroom')))
             
    }" value="value a"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OR/AND was all confused, it should have been OR(A,AND(B,C),AND(D,E)). I realize this looks weird, as you were probably expecting it to look like A OR(B AND C)OR(D AND E), but that's not how formulas work.

Also, to return true or false, you don't need IF; a Boolean value is already a Boolean value (I know this sounds obvious, but so many people seem to miss this obvious detail). There was also a stray `!` that would have negated your final "CONTAINS", which I think was in error, based on what you stated in your probem statement. Here's a revised edition that I think reflects your intent.

```
{!
    OR(
        CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing'), 
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety__c, 'entering or exiting the home/answering the door'), 
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing/self care in bathroom')
        ),
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety__c, 'confusion or dimentia'), 
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing/self care in bathroom')
        )
    )
}" value="value a"/>
```

As a matter of efficiency, you can even remove the redundant bits with another OR as well:

```
{!
    OR(
        CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing'), 
        AND(
            CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c, 'toileting/bathing/self care in bathroom'),
            OR(
                CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety__c, 'entering or exiting the home/answering the door'), 
                CONTAINS(Intake__c.Safety__c, 'confusion or dimentia'), 
            )                
        )
    )
}" value="value a"/>
```

Comment: This is definitely what I'm looking for! Is it also possible to ad an 'OR' argument into one of the and statments? Like OR Intake__c.Safety__c contains 'entering or exiting' AND Intake__c.Personal_Care__c contains 'toileting/bathing' Becomes OR  Intake__c.Safety__c contains 'entering or exiting' AND (Intake__c.Personal_Care__c contains 'toileting/bathing' OR 'hygene')

Comment: @AlexisFrisch You can nest them pretty deep if you need to, see my final revision. It'd be more like `AND(...OR(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c,'toileting/bathing'),contains(intake__c.personal_Care__c,'hygene')))`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help!